# how to show and use Radio button in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to have two radio buttons in my Asp.Net MVC3 App.There is no field in my Database representing these Radio button.
So i cant use them this way

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Monthly)
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Yearly)
```

I  have tried to use this to show my radio button

```
 @Html.Label("Monthly","Monthly")
 @Html.RadioButton("Monthly","Monthlyy")
 @Html.Label("Yearly","Yearly")
 @Html.RadioButton("Yearly","Yearly")
```

The buttons are visible but the user can select both the buttons together.Whereas i want that only one button can be checked at a time.
Also i would be needing the label of the checked radio button for further functionality of my App.How can i add the radio button and how can i get the label(**text value**) of the checked radio button.

Please guide how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you to be able to group the radio buttons, they need to have the same name. i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"/>
```

So in your case, what you want to do is the following

```
@Html.Label("Monthly")
@Html.RadioButton("MonthlyOrYearly", "Monthly")
@Html.Label("Yearly")
@Html.RadioButton("MonthlyOrYearly", "Yearly")
```

Comment: Ok Thanks.
And how can i get the Label(Text) of the selected(checked) radio Button?
I want to have the Text of the Selected Radio in a Variable in my Controller.
`var radText=Checked Radio Button Text`