# How do get these two lines to be the same context in Razor synatx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So the beginning of my View is

```
@foreach ( var G in ViewBag.GroupedBySec )
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-striped assessment-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="black-n-white" colspan="4">@G.Key</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Section</td><td>Component</td><td>Completeness Level (0-100%)</td><td>Readines</td>
                </tr>
                @var GroupedBySubsection = G.GroupBy(x => x.SubsectionTitle);
                @foreach ( var g in GroupedBySubsection )
                {
                    @foreach ( var qa in g )
                    {
```

and I'm getting errors on the

```
@var GroupedBySubsection = G.GroupBy(x => x.SubsectionTitle);
@foreach ( var g in GroupedBySubsection )
```

lines which say

> The name 'var' does not exist in the current context

and

> The name 'GroupedBySection' does not exist in the current context

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively, any suggestions for how I can get a C# object that has the entire groupings and subgroupings so that I don't have to write all this crap in my View?

My Controller method for this page is like

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Peek ( Guid pid )
    {
        ViewBag.PartnerId = pid;
        List<AnswerInfo> AllAnswers = this._Db.GetAnswersByPartner(pid);
        ViewBag.GroupedBySec = AllAnswers.GroupBy(A => A.SectionTitle);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: `@{ var GroupedBySubsection = G.GroupBy(x => x.SubsectionTitle); }`

Comment: And create a view model  _so that I don't have to write all this crap in my View_

Comment: @StephenMuecke That causes a `Cannot use a lamba experssion as an argument to a dynamically dispatched ...` on the `x => x.SubsectionTitle`

Comment: Give me 10 min and I'll test it :)

Comment: I cannot repeat that error, but what is `G`? Your `foreach` loop suggests its a object, not a collection so it would not have a `GroupBy()` method. Are you already doing some grouping in the controller?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I do the first set of grouping in my controller

Comment: OK, now I understand - `G` is `dynamic` so you need to cast it - e.g. `@{ var GroupedBySubsection = ((IEnumerable<yourModel>)G).GroupBy(x => x.SubsectionTitle); }` making you view even uglier :) - Use a view model.

Comment: Have just seen your next question. Is there any point me adding an answer and showing you how to do the view model and linq query in the controller?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I would be eternally greatful if you could convince me to use a view model

Comment: Need a break, but I'll add something in an hour - after which your going to kick yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because your missing the braces around your `var` statement. It should be

```
@{ var GroupedBySubsection = G.GroupBy(x => x.SubsectionTitle); }
```

This will then throw a different error because you referring an item in `ViewBag` which is `dynamic` so you need to cast it as follows

```
@{ var GroupedBySubsection = ((IEnumerable<yourModel>)G).GroupBy(x => x.SubsectionTitle); }
```

making your view even uglier.

> how I can get a C# object that has the entire groupings and subgroupings so that I don't have to write all this crap in my View?

Use a view model. Based on some of your previous question, you have a data model which (abbreviated) is

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string SubSection { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And that you want to group it in the view by `Section` and then `SubSection`. Your view models would then be

```
public class SectionVM
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public List<SubSectionVM> SubSections { get; set; }
}
public class SubSectionVM
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionVM> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class QuestionVM
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Your controller code would then be

```
var answers = db.Answers..... // your previous query

List<SectionVM> model = answers.GroupBy(x => x.Section).Select(x => new SectionVM
{
    Title = x.Key,
    SubSections = x.GroupBy(y => y.SubSection).Select(y => new SubSectionVM
    {
        Title = y.Key,
        Questions = y.Select(z => new QuestionVM
        {
            QuestionID = z.QuestionID,
            QuestionText = z.QuestionText,
            ....
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model List<SectionVM>
@foreach(var section in Model)
{
    <h2>@section.Title</h2>
    foreach(var subSection in section.SubSections)
    {
        <h3>@subSection.Title</h3>
        foreach(var question in subSection.Questions)
        {
            <p>@question.QuestionText</p>
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Side note:  I have made the collection properties `List<T>` assuming that you might want to also generate a form for editing the Questions/Answers and to do so you will need a `for` loop which required the collection to implement `IList`. Alternatively you could save the extra overhead of `.ToList(), keep them as`IEnumerable`and use a custom`EditorTemplate` for each view model type.

For an example of how an edit view might look (using the `for` loop option), refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055287/asp-net-mvc-5-group-of-radio-buttons/28057533#28057533).

Comment: I have been fully conviced that the view model is the answer to all my problems in life