# Model design / model binding on nested complex type in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following model structure:

Form > Form Sections > FormQuestions > FormQuestionOptions (options are for option items in dropdown lists / radio button lists).

I have scaffolded the views for creating and editing the Form, FormSection, FormQuestion ok.

Now I want to create a view that will dynamically generate a Form Instance based on passing the form ID. I can generate the form controls for the FormInstance but cannot work out how to bind the dynamically generated controls which are generated based on the FormQuestion model.

```
`public class Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        FormSections = new List<FormSection>();
    }

    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int FormId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public List<FormSection> FormSections { get; set; }

}

public class FormSection
{

    public FormSection()
    {
        FormQuestions = new List<FormQuestion>();
    }

    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int FormSectionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Form")]
    public int FormId { get; set; }

    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OrderById { get; set; }

    public IList<FormQuestion> FormQuestions { get; set; }


}

public class FormQuestion
{
    public FormQuestion()
    {
        FormQuestionOptions = new HashSet<FormQuestionOption>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int FormQuestionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Form Section")]
    public int FormSectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual FormSection FormSection { get; set; }

    public string ControlName
    { 
        get
        {
            return "q" + this.FormQuestionId.ToString();
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Control Type")]
    public int ControlTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ControlType ControlType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Data Type")]
    public int DataTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataType DataType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OrderById { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name ="Additional Question Description")]
    public string AdditionalDescription { get; set; }

    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string HelpTip { get; set; }

    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Answer {get; set; }

    public ICollection<FormQuestionOption> FormQuestionOptions { get; set; }

}

public class FormQuestionOption
{
    public int FormQuestionOptionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Form Question")]
    public int FormQuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual FormQuestion FormQuestion { get; set; }

    public string OptionText { get; set; }

}
`
```

In my FormInstances.cs controller There is a GET and a POST Create action. The  POST Create action should if there is a model error - rebind the answers given by the user in the dynamically generated controls. However think that the 'Answer' field on the FormQuestion is not in the right place in the model as when do the POST the 'Answer' in the database is always blank.

How can I change the model so the Answer can be bound to the dynamically generated form controls? I suspect Answer belongs somewhere on the FormInstance class, not on the Form class?

```
`// GET: FormInstances/Create
    public IActionResult Create(int formId)
    {
        Form frm = _context.Forms
            .Include(f => f.FormSections)
                .ThenInclude(fs => fs.FormQuestions)
                    .ThenInclude(fq => fq.FormQuestionOptions)
            .Include(f => f.FormSections)
                .ThenInclude(fs => fs.FormQuestions)
                    .ThenInclude(fq => fq.ControlType)
            .Where(f => f.FormId == formId).First();
        FormInstance fi = new FormInstance();
        fi.FormId = formId;
        fi.Form = frm;

        return View(fi);
    }

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FormInstanceId,FormId,Surname,Forename,Address,PostCode,DOB,DateSubmitted")] FormInstance formInstance)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // TODO: Write form data to text file 

            //_context.Add(formInstance);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        // recreate the Form
        Form frm = _context.Forms
            .Include(f => f.FormSections)
                .ThenInclude(fs => fs.FormQuestions)
                    .ThenInclude(fq => fq.FormQuestionOptions)
            .Include(f => f.FormSections)
                .ThenInclude(fs => fs.FormQuestions)
                    .ThenInclude(fq => fq.ControlType)
            .Where(f => f.FormId == formInstance.FormId).First();

        // set the FormInstance Form property
        formInstance.Form = frm;

        return View(formInstance);
    }
`
```

My View - /FormInstances/Create.cshtml

```
`
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.Form.FormSections.Count; x++)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">@Model.Form.FormSections[x].Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions.Count; i++) 
            {
                @if(Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].ControlType.Title.ToLower() == "label")
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-info">@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Title</div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-label" for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].ControlName">@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Title</label>

                        @if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].AdditionalDescription))
                                    {
                            <div> @Html.Raw(Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].AdditionalDescription) </div>

                        }
                        @switch(Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].ControlType.Title.ToLower())
                                    {
                            case "textbox":
                                <input type = "text" asp-for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Answer" class="form-control" required="@(Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Mandatory == true ? "required" : "")" />
                                break;

                            case "textbox multiline":
                                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Answer" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                break;

                            case "drop down list":
                                <select asp-for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Answer" class="form-control">
                                    <option value = "" > ---Please Select ---</option>
                                    @foreach(FormQuestionOption fqo in Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].FormQuestionOptions)
                                    {
                                        <option> @fqo.OptionText </option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                                break;

                            case "radio button list":
                                foreach (FormQuestionOption fqo in Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].FormQuestionOptions)
                                {
                                    <p>
                                        <input type = "radio" asp-for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Answer" value="@fqo.OptionText" />
                                        @fqo.OptionText
                                    </p>
                                }
                                break;

                            case "checkbox":
                                <input type="checkbox" for="Form.FormSections[@x].FormQuestions[@i].@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Answer" />
                                break;

                            default:
                                <div class="alert alert-warning">Unknown Control Type</div>
                                break;

                        }
                </div>
}

            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
`
```

**EDIT**
Sorry but this is my first MVC project after webforms. Thanks for your feedback. I have created a new model structure below.
1) Is it valid to inherit to inherit from the Question class for TextQuestion, YesNoQuestion and MultipleChoiceQuestion?
2) Would I be able to order the mixture of TextQuestion, YesNoQuestion and MultipleChoiceQuestion by the OrderById property or would this mess up the indexes for model binding? Would I need to combine the 3 lists of questions into a parent list ? How would that affect the ability to use EditorFor ?

```
`
public class Form
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<FormSection> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class FormSection
{
    public int FormSectionId { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int OrderById { get; set; }
    public List<TextQuestion> TextQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<YesNoQuestion> YesNoQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<MultipleChoiceQuestion> MultipleChoiceQuestions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int FormSectionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string HelpTip { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
    public int OrderById { get; set; }
}

public class TextQuestion : Question
{
    public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class YesNoQuestion : Question
{
    public bool? YesNoAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class MultipleChoiceQuestion : Question
{
    public List<MultipleChoiceOption> MultipleChoiceOptions { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedMultipleChoiceOptionId { get; set; }
}

public class MultipleChoiceOption
{
    public int MultipleChoiceOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// need to display:
// Form.Title
// Each FormSection.Title, 
// Each TextQuestion, YesNoQuestion, MultipleChoiceQuestion needs displaying
// along with the appropriate control for receiving an answer, therefore also need:
// also FormSection.TextQuestions, FormSection.YesNoQuestions, FormSection.MulitpleChoiceQuestions
// which will enable to use:
// TextQuestion.Title, TextQuestion.HelpTip, TextQuestion.TextAnswer, TextQuestion.Mandatory
// YesNoQuestion.Title, YesNoQuestion.HelpTip, YesNoQuestion.YesNoAnswer
// MultipleChoiceQuestion.Title, MultipleChoiceQuestion.HelpTip, MultipleChoiceQuestion.Mandatory, MultipleChoiceOption.MultipleChoiceOptions, MultipleChoiceQuestion.SelectedMultipleChoiceOptionId, 
// Also additional fields (DateSubmitted and SubmittedBy) that are required for all forms
public class FormInstanceVM
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string FormTitle { get; set; }

    public List<FormSection> Sections { get; set; }
    public List<TextQuestion> TextQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<YesNoQuestion> YesNoQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<MultipleChoiceQuestion> MultipleChoiceQuestions { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }

}

// controller

// /FormInstances/Create
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int formId)
{
  // get form and its sections and questions from database
  // create a FormInstanceVM using the Form object and return the VM
}

// /FormInstances/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormInstanceVM fi)
{
    // get form data from ViewModel passed from form
}
`
```

Comment: There are numerous issues with your code. In your `switch` block, its its a `"textbox"` you use `asp-for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].Answer"` but your model does not even have a property with that name. The if its one of the other types, you use `asp-for="@Model.Form.FormSections[x].FormQuestions[i].ControlName"` but `ControlName` is a readonly property so it could not be set anyway. And even if had a getter, binding to that would not make sense.

Comment: Even if you do have an `Answer` property, then binding the value of a textbox and dropdownlist to the same property would suggest your models/database design is not correct.

Comment: Most importantly, do use data models in a view, especially when editing data. Always use a view model to represent what you need in the view - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). For an example which is just using radio buttons, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055287/asp-net-mvc-5-group-of-radio-buttons/28057533#28057533)

Comment: You currently have no server side validation for the answer - the `required` attribute is HTML-5 client side validation only and you need to use a conditional validation attribute (e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute) so that you get proper client and server side validation based on your `Mandatory` property.

Comment: Your `switch` statements also mean that you can be submitting name/value pairs for non-zero based/non-consecutive indexers which would cause model binding to fail.

Comment: Then you have a POST method which binds to typeof `FormInstance` but its not clear if thats the model in your view, but in any case it includes a `[BindAttribute]` which prevents of any the form controls you have shown from binding anyway.

Comment: I have updated the code so the Answer property is now on the FormQuestion and the EditorFor statements in the switch now use the Answer field as originally intended.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So I need to create a FormInstanceVM - can you advise is the best way to structure this if I need to create a form based on the values stored in the database but then store an Instance of the form in the database?

Comment: I gave you an example in the 3rd comment. And forget you database for the moment, and concentrate on creating a model that represents your view and getting model binding and validation - your database will almost certainly need to be changed anyway.

Comment: You will not be able to use a `sting Answer` property for your Yes/No (checkbox) questions, or your multiple choice questions (you will likely need separate tables relating to 'text', 'multiple choice' and 'yes/no' questions and answers)

Comment: I have edited my question at the bottom to provide a new model structure.

Comment: You cannot just keep adding new questions (you need to ask a new question) - trying to answer all this would require a small book chapter. But to summarize, (1) An `Answer` is not a `Question` so you should have a separate view model class for an answer (with a relationship to `Question` and to the user) - (2) Not as you have currently structured it in your edit.