# ASP.NET MVC Multiple choice survey

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I'm creating a simple survey using ASP.NET MVC. 
The administrator will create questions answerable by 3 options only - *Strongly agree*, *somewhat agree*, *strongly disagree*) via the Create View.

The user will then have to select their answer using radiobutton.

1. How should I add it in my view?

Currently, this is how my view looks like (I know this is still wrong as im still trying to understand how to do this correctly):

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Question
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            Strongly Agree
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            Somewhat Agree
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            Strongly Disagree
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.Answer, "Strongly Agree", new { QuestionID = item.QuestionID })
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.Answer, "Somewhat Agree", new { QuestionID = item.QuestionID })
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.Answer, "Strongly Disagree", new { QuestionID = item.QuestionID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

2. How would I get the selected answer of the user for each question and save it to my database?

My tables are as follows:

**tblTestProper:** [`QuestionID`, `UserID`, `Answer`]

**tblQuestions:** [`QuestionID`, `Question`]

Are there any examples or ideas I can follow to achieve this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: how does your Controller looks like?

Comment: You need to give those Radio Buttons a specific value so when you read the item.Answer it will have your selected value in it.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055287/asp-net-mvc-5-group-of-radio-buttons/28057533#28057533) for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="text-center">Strongly Agree</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Somewhat Agree</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Strongly Disagree</th>
                </tr>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>   
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].AnswerID)</td>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].QuestionID)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Question)</td>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].QuestionTag)</td>
                        <td align="right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Answer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Answer, 1)</td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Answer, 2)</td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Answer, 3)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, code-only questions without any explanation tend to get flagged for deletion as they are seen to be "low quality".  Please read the section on answering questions in the help area.

Answer (score 0):

**I think hope you helpful this**

html code like this

```
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">1<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug1" value="1"></label>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">2<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug1" value="2"></label>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">3<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug1" value="3"></label>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">4<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug1" value="4"></label>
    <!--qug1 = Question Group 1-->
    </br>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">1<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug2" value="1"></label>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">2<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug2" value="2"></label>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">3<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug2" value="3"></label>
    <label class="form-radio form-normal active form-text">4<input type="radio" class="rdomcqans" name="qug2" value="4"></label>
    <!--qug2 = Question Group 2-->
    <input type="hidden" id="McqAnswerListArray" name="McqAnswerListArray" />

    <script>
        $('.rdomcqans').on('change', function () {
            var McqAnswerListArray="";
            var count = 0;
            McqAnswerListArray += "";
            $('.rdomcqans:checked').each(function () {

                if (count == 0) {            
                    McqAnswerListArray += $(this).attr('name')+ ":" + $(this).val();
                } else {
                    McqAnswerListArray += ",";
                    McqAnswerListArray += $(this).attr('name') + ":" + $(this).val();
                }

                count++;
            });

            $('#McqAnswerListArray').val(McqAnswerListArray);
        });
    </script>
```

Controller Should be like this

You should be import *using Newtonsoft.Json;*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MCQ(String McqAnswerListArray) {
    string[] Jsonn = mcm.McqAnswerListArray.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < Jsonn.Count(); i++) {
        string s = Jsonn[i];
        string[] obj = s.Split(':');
        string strqid = obj[0].ToString();
        int qid = Convert.ToInt32(strqid.Substring(3, strqid.Length - 3));//Get Question Group Number
        int Answer = Convert.ToInt32(obj[1].ToString());//Get Group Answer
        //You Can save Your answer bellow
    }
}
```