# Unable to bind group of radiobuttons in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I'm making a feedback form on mvc 5 and the feedback form consists of 10 questions having 5 selected answers each. Those selected answers are the group of radio buttons that I'm populating. But in post action method, the radio buttons are not getting bind. Below is my code.

**Model.cs**

```
public class FeedbackForm
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Models.Questionnaire mquestions { get; set; }
        public List<Questionnaire> Question { get; set; }
        public Batches batches { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }


    }

    public class Questionnaire
    {
        public string QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int? SelectedAnswer { get; set; } // for binding
        public IEnumerable<QuestionnaireStatus> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
    }

    public class QuestionnaireStatus
    {
        public string StatusId { get; set; }
        public string StatusTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Models.FeedbackForm> lstfeedback = new List<Models.FeedbackForm>();
            Models.FeedbackForm form = new Models.FeedbackForm();


            Context.FeedBackForm contFeedback = new Context.FeedBackForm();

            Models.FeedbackForm vm = new Models.FeedbackForm();

            form.Question = new List<Models.Questionnaire>();
            form.Question = contFeedback.GetAllQuestionnaire();

            for (int i = 0; i < form.Question.Count; i++)
            {

                lstfeedback.Add(new Models.FeedbackForm
                {
                    Question = new List<Models.Questionnaire>()
                    { new Models.Questionnaire
                    {
                        QuestionId = form.Question[i].QuestionId,
                        QuestionTitle = form.Question[i].QuestionTitle
                    ,
                        PossibleAnswers = contFeedback.GetAllStatus()
                    },

                }
                });
            }


            return View(lstfeedback);
        }
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @*@Html.Display("Questions")*@
            </th>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Question.Count; j++)
                {

                        foreach (var item in Model[i].Question[j].PossibleAnswers)
                        {
                            <th>
                                @item.StatusTitle
                            </th>

                        }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }

        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Question.Count; j++)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>Model[i].Question[j].QuestionTitle)
                    </td>

                    foreach (var item in Model[i].Question[j].PossibleAnswers)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model[i].Question[j].SelectedAnswer, item.StatusId, new { id = item.StatusId })
                        </td>
                    }

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Question[j].SelectedAnswer)

                }

            </tr>
        }

    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="Attendance" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You models are not really making sense. you want to bind the selected radio button to a `int? SelectedAnswer` property, but the `PossibleAnswers` is typeof `QuestionnaireStatus` which does not contain any `int` properties (and the name `QuestionnaireStatus` does not sound right anyway - is that really the class that describes a 'possible answer'?)

Comment: Yes it does, I actually took some idea from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055287/asp-net-mvc-5-group-of-radio-buttons

Comment: No it does not - it contains 2 `string` properties! And that is my answer :)

Comment: And you have not even shown your POST method

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. It was the simple mistake i was doing. Thanks anyway. Now its working. Thank you @StephenMuecke :)

Comment: And suggest you name you classes to be a bit more descriptive of what they actually represent :)

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks again :)