# Cannot submit selected option to contoller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Cart viewmodel is

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public List<PaymentMethods> PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

My PaymentMethods class

```
public partial class PaymentMethods
{
    public int PaymentMethodID { get; set; }
    public string PaymentName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

My view is

```
@foreach (PaymentMethods pm in Model.PaymentMethod)
  {
      if (pm.Active)
      {
          <li>
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.PaymentMethod, pm.PaymentMethodID, new { id = "pay" + pm.PaymentMethodID, @class = "paymethod" })
              <label for="@("pay" + pm.PaymentMethodID)" class="checkbox">@pm.PaymentName</label>
          </li>
      }
   }
```

And the controller accepts the CartViewModel as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CartViewModel CartViewModel)
{

}
```

The question is why when i choose a Payment method and submit the form, the controller has PaymentMethod.Count equal to zero?

The selection is not passed on the controller. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: the lamda should point to the selected variable and not to the list.  see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174475/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-mvc-4-razor/22174654#22174654

Comment: Where are you adding a Payment method to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempting to bind a radio button group to a collection of complex objects. A radio button only posts the value of the selected button (in your case the value of the selected `PaymentMethodID` property). You need a separate property in your model to bind to.

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public int SelectedPaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PaymentMethods> PaymentMethods { get; set; }
}
```

and modify your view to

```
@foreach (PaymentMethods pm in Model.PaymentMethod)
{
    <li>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.SelectedPaymentMethod, pm.PaymentMethodID, new { id = "", @class = "paymethod" })
            <span>@pm.PaymentName</span>
        </label>
    </li>
}
```

Now when you submit the form, the value of `SelectedPaymentMethod` will be the value of the selected `PaymentMethodID` property.

Side note: Rather than including the `if (pm.Active)` statement in the view, consider filtering the collection in the controller (e.g. `model.PaymentMethods = db.PaymentMethods.Where(p => p.IsActive);`)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with name generation of Radio buttons and due to which ModelBinding does not happen at server. Also you should have an item binding for selected item.

Add the model property as

```
public int SelectedPayMethodID { get; set;}
```

Change the implementation as follows

```
@for (int index =0; index < Model.PaymentMethod; index++)
  {
      if (Model.PaymentMethod[index].Active)
      {
          <li>
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedPayMethodID, Model.PaymentMethod[index].PaymentMethodID, new { id = "pay" + Model.PaymentMethod[index].PaymentMethodID, @class = "paymethod" })
              <label for="@("pay" + Model.PaymentMethod[index].PaymentMethodID)" class="checkbox">@pm.PaymentName</label>
          </li>
      }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't even compile

Comment: just test it, you have everything for it

Comment: Not sure, why it has vote down? Is it not the answer to question?