# @Html.CheckboxFor not displaying in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The checkbox is not displaying in page. I tried many solutions in google.  Nothing worked. Here s the code:

```
@model project.gamestatus

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Calculator", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmID" }))
{

        //other codes

        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Show on Screen", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.display_status)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.display_status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Only if the checkbox is shown in page i can proceed with validation. In my view there is no checkbox

Comment: you haven't set a value on your check box.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174475/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-mvc-4-razor/22174654#22174654

Comment: What do you mean its not showing? You have a `CheckBoxFor()` method that will generate the html (a `<input type="checkbox" .. />` and a `<input type="hidden" ... />`) for the property which you can easily verify by inspectinh the page source. If you not seeing it visually, then you probably have an issue with your css.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  When i inspected the html code i found it has a css property "display:none" along with it. so the checkbox is not showing in view

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to ensure that the display_status model is of boolean type and assigned the display name to it along with any validation.

```
[Display(Name="CheckBox Display Name")]
[Required]
public bool display_status { get; set; }
```

Also, @Html.CheckBoxFor do not support the label of checkbox. Therefore, you can have the label of the checkbox using @Html.LabelFor as follow:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Show on Screen", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.display_status)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.display_status)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.display_status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i checked in inspector and it always has a css property "display:none" which is autogenerated by the helper

Answer (score 2):

though its a very old post but I undergo this issue todat, but when I inspected I found that the CSS property opacity was set to 0 so changing it to 1 will solve the issue

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active, new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "opacity: 1" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting the height to 20px explicitly. When I examined the page, it was being set to 20%:

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExistingUser, new { style="height:20px"  })